# Implementation of tags on resources in resource group using Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, tags, azure-resource-group

I am trying to put tags on resources and resource group using Powershell.
The problem is it remove existing tags and add the new tags.

**Powershell Script** :

```
Get-AzureRmResourceGroup "testvsoRG" | Set-AzureRmResourceGroup -Tag @{Environment="UAT";Location="USA";DNS="www.xyz.com";Timezone="PST";Phase="Live"}

$resourceGroupName="testvsoRG"
$tags_to_apply=(Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroupName).tags
Find-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName | foreach 
{
    Set-AzureRmResource -ResourceId $_.resourceid -Tag $tags_to_apply -Force
}
```

**What i want**
Suppose I have 3 tags. I will provide resource group and it should add these 3 tags to the resource group and its resources. The resource group and its resource already have some tags in it. I want to keep those tags as it is and if my new tags matches the existing ones then it should update it.

**For only resource group**

```
$h = @{1="one";2="two";3="three"}
$resourceGroupName="testvsoRG"
$group=(Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroupName).tags
foreach ($key in $group.Keys)
{
    if ($h.ContainsKey($key))
    {
        $group.Remove($key)
    }
}
$group += $h
write-host $group
```

**Error**

```
System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.
Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry
```

**Add tags in Azure Resource Group Resources**

```
$resources = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName 
foreach ($r in $resources)
{
    $resourcetags = (Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceId $r.ResourceId).Tags    
    foreach ($rkey in $resourcetags.Keys)
    {
        if ($h.ContainsKey($rkey))
        {
            $resourcetags.Remove($rkey)
        }
    }
    $resourcetags += $h
    Set-AzureRmResource -Tag $resourcetags -ResourceId $r.ResourceId -Force
}
```

**Error**

```
Get-AzureRmResource : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `$tags_to_apply=(Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroupName).tags`, the `$tags_to_apply` will be a hashtable.

> The resource group and its resource already have some tags in it. I want to keep those tags as it is and if my new tags matches the existing ones then it should update it.

Per my understanding, you want to add new items in the hashtable, if the item is existing in the hashtable, update it. You could refer to my sample command, it works fine on my side.

```
$hashtable = @{1="one";2="two";3="three"}
$h = @{4="four";2="two2"}
foreach($key in $($hashtable.keys)){
    if ($h.ContainsKey($key)){
        $hashtable.Remove($key)
    }
}
$hashtable += $h
```

[image]

**Update**:

It may caused by a mix of `int` and `string` because of the key name, I change the key name, and it works fine.

First, set the `Tag`.

```
$resourceGroupName = "resourceGroupName"
Set-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroupName -Tag @{tag1="one";tag2="two2";tag3="three"}
```

Second, set the `Tag` with new hash table.

```
$h = @{tag2="two";tag4="four"}
$resourceGroupName="resourceGroupName"
$group=(Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroupName).Tags
foreach($key in $($group.keys))
{
    if(!$key){
    if ($h.ContainsKey($key)){
        $group.Remove($key)
    }
   }
}
$group += $h
Set-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroupName -Tag $group
```

[image]

Comment: I am new to Powershell and azure. It will take some time for me to implement this.

Comment: Let go one by one. Firstly i am trying to do it for only resource group but it gives error. See the added code.

Comment: @rAJ You could refer to my update, any question just ask.

Comment: Thanks for the update. It works fine when you have to add new tags or update existing one but it does not retain the existing tags. I don't want to remove existing tags.

Comment: @rAJ The command will not remove existing tags, could you see the `1`and `3` still exist? It just remove the old existing one.

Comment: In your example you again give the 1 and 3 along with 2. That's why it is displayed in result. Try to send only 2 in your hash and see the 1 and 3 will remove.

Comment: @rAJ Sorry for my oversight, see my update, note: the `Tag` has been changed to `Tags`.

Comment: Perfect Joy! Now first part is complete. Now i want to do the same thing for all the resources inside this resource group. I am going to try this and if i will stuck anywhere then will ask you for help.

Comment: @rAJ  Glad to help you, if my reply solved your issue, much appreciated if you can mark it.

Comment: Hey Joy! can you resolve the issue? I updated the question for second part. There is no problem in execution. It successfully updated the tags but error displayed in console.

Comment: @rAJ I will check it tomorrow.

Comment: ok no problem. Thanks for the help. If i able to resolve it today then i will update the post.

Comment: I got it. Add the line at the top of the code. $ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'

Comment: Issue still persist with VSO release job. When i run it locally then it is working fine. Error : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters. On this line : $resources = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName

Comment: @rAJ It is strange, but I am not familiar with VSO, I recommend you to ask the question in another post, maybe it will be better.

Comment: Finally found the solution for VSO job. use Find-AzureRmResource instead of Get-AzureRmResource. $resources = Find-AzureRmResource  -ResourceGroupNameContains $resourceGroupName

Comment: @rAJ It sounds great.

Comment: Again got a error. If the resource does not already have atleast one tag then it is failed. [error]Exception calling "ContainsKey" with "1" argument(s): "Key cannot be null.

Comment: If the resource does not have tag, how about just use Set-AzureRmResource ？

Comment: It may or may not have tags. I added null check and now it is working fine. updated the answer.